# How should I incorporate different types of files into a database of products?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, filemaker

**Context**: I recently started a new job. I found my colleagues were exchanging information (product spec sheets, 3D renderings, etc) via files and email, which creates the infuriating situation where there are multiple versions of files being passed around. I decided to start building a solution using FileMaker to resolve this, mainly because I'm not really a technical person and FileMaker seems pretty easy to understand. I have been learning both database design and FileMaker literally from scratch.

**Purpose**: The solution will needs to be able to do the following:

1. Allow central management of data and files
2. Export a product roadmap for sales people
3. Export current product catalogue for sales people
4. Export product spec sheets

This, in my mind, will help everyone by maintaining a single set of accurate data which can be exported in different views.

**Question**: What is the best way to incorporate different types of files into the database?

For some views, I would like to be able to show related files, including 3D renderings, images, SoC data sheets, user manuals, etc. What would the schema look like?

Regarding files, I have the following tables:

- Files (FileID, FileFormatID, FileName, FileTypeID, FileContainer, DateCommited, DateModified, TimeModified, Comment)
- FileFormats (FileFormatID, FileFormat), where FileFormat is svg, pdf, Word, png, jpg, etc...
- FileTypes (FileTypeID, FileType), where FileType is 3D Rendering, Gerber, Photo, Certification, QIG, etc...

**Solution generated by my feeble mind**:

- ProductFiles (ProductID, FileID), where ProductID is the key in a Products table.
- SoC_Files (SoC_ModelNo, FileID), where SoC_ModelNo is the key in an SoC table.

This way I can include in my views a list of files related to a product or SoC, showing only the FileTypes or FileFormats I need.

However, this seems messy. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks! It's my first question on StackOverflow, so please let me know if the question is unclear or inappropriate in any way.

EDIT: The SoCs are not products themselves, they're used in the products. Some customers want that information. Each file can belong to multiple products or SoCs, and each product or SoC can have more than one file.

Comment: i am not sure what exactly your question is. Is every file related to (at most) one product? What is the difference between a product and a SoC (IOW, why aren't SoCs included in the Products table)?

Comment: read up on database subtype/supertype or "table inheritance"

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ah. The SoCs are not products themselves, they're used in the products. Some customers want that information. Each file can belong to multiple products or SoCs, and each product or SoC can have more than one file.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect we need more information about what your solution is about. If it's chiefly about documentation, then the differences between the objects being documented are most likely irrelevant.

In any case, you describe a many-to-many relationship between Files and Products - so you should have a *join table* between these two, where each combination of file-to-product will be stored as an individual record.

If it turns out that you do need a separate SoC table, you could turn the join table into a "star-join" table - meaning it would have fields for:

- FileID
- ProductID
- SoCID

and in each record either the ProductID or the SoCID field would be empty.

Note that in Filemaker you have another option to establish a many-to-many relationship: you could use a checkbox in the Files table to select the products which the file documents. However, in such case, (1) you won't be able to record anything about a specific file-to-product join and (2) it will be more difficult to produce a report of files-by-product or vice versa.

The FileFormats table is redundant and can be replaced by a custom value list: file extensions are unique and unchanging, and you have nothing to record about any of them. I have a feeling the same is true about the FileTypes table.

An exception to the above: if you can have multiple versions of the **same** file in different formats, you may need to add another table for the physical files.

Comment: The FileTypes table is to leave open the possibility for a form that displays all product images, or one that displays all mechanical or electronics related information; FileFormat is for further fine-tuned views, such as: only product photos and 3D rendering with extension .png because marketing people will need images with transparent backgrounds. But now that you mention it, it does seem rather meaningless...

Comment: "*The FileTypes table is to leave open the possibility for a form that displays all product images ..*" That possibility (as well as all other ones)  remains open.